# Active monitoring and scheduled scanning in ClamXav?

Tags: anti-virus

I want to use an antivirus app on my Mac, and I heard that [ClamXav](http://www.clamxav.com/index.php) is a good one to use. However, I'm not sure how to use it.

All previous anti-virus scanners that I have used have two main features:

1. Active monitoring
2. Scheduled scanning

The first feature constantly monitors your system and when it detects a new virus file being created, it will let you know so that you can remove the virus before it does any damage.

The second feature will periodically (e.g. every week) scan your entire hard-drive to make sure that no viruses have made their way onto your hard-drive.

Is there any way to enable these two features in ClamXav?

Comment: Would you accept details of another AV solution? Or are you set with ClamXav?

Comment: @VxJasonxV: If the solution is better than ClamXav, it would be useful to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory read of ClamXav's online documentation, it appears that both of those features are available.

1. For Active monitoring, ClamXav allows you to specify any number of folders to watch (e.g. your Downloads folder) as well as having a way to scan incoming email and inserted disks.
2. For Scheduling scanning, there is a preference pane which allows you to both schedule virus definition updates and perform periodic scans.

I would recommend reading their [online documentation](http://www.clamxav.com/documentation.php).

Answer (score 0):

[Sophos AV](http://www.sophos.com/products/free-tools/free-mac-anti-virus/) has been very active in educating the Mac Community that Mac Viruses DO exist. If you are concerned about this fact, then they have a free software solution.

It scans automatically in the background, and can be launched as-needed as well.